# Extract first/second/third word containing X in google sheets

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Is it possible to extract pieces of text in a sentence containing X in a google sheet. In a Formula of via Apps script. I couldn't find a decent answer on google or didn't know what to search for.

For example:

A1: [Peter] kicks the [ball] to [Shaun].

I want to extract the first word containing '[' & ']' in B1, the second word containing '[' & ']' in C1, et cetera.

So:
[image]

| A | B | C | D |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [Peter] kicks the [ball] to [Shaun]. | [Peter] | [ball] | [Shaun] |  |

Comment: One example is not enough to establish a pattern or rule around which to build a formula. Consider sharing a link to a spreadsheet that contains, say, 10 or 20 *realistic* rows of source data. At the very least, identify what the maximum number of such inclusions will be. And will all entries in the source range be strings with at least *one* such instance? Do you actually want the square brackets extracted with the words?

Comment: In addition, knowing a few other things will help. Are there headers? What is the actual sheet name and range where the source data resides? Are you wanting the results to be returned in the same sheet or a different sheet? Whatever the case, it can be accomplished with a single array formula; but more details are necessary. (Again, the most efficient and fool-proof way to convey those many details is to simply share a link to the spreadsheet (or to a copy of it, or to a spreadsheet set up the same way and containing a realistic and sufficient sample from it).

Comment: Something like `=INDEX(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(\[[^\[\]]*\])|.","$1"),"]")&"]")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
=regexextract(A1,regexreplace(regexreplace(A1,"[\[]","(\\\["),"[\]]","\\\])"))
```

Comment: I add a simplier solution

Answer (score 0):

#### Extracting words and posting them to sheet

```
function lfunko() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  let a = sh.getRange("A1").getValue();
  let o = a.toString().match(/\[[A-Za-z]+\]/g).map(e => e);
  sh.getRange(1, 2, 1, o.length).setValues([o]);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
}
```

Sheeto:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [Peter] kicks the [ball] ot [Shaun]. | [Peter] | [ball] | [Shaun] |